# Swap condition in quick sort partition procedure (Lomuto)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have implemented the quick sort from the book Introduction to algorithms. the book specifies the procedure as following

[image]

However **I fail to see the requirement of less than equal comparison on line 4, shouldn't only less than comparison suffice**.

To check I have written the following program and it worked correcttly on data set that I have tested.

```
private fun partition(start: Int, end: Int, arr: Array<Int>) : Int{
        var pivotIndex = end
        var maximumElementIndex = start
        for(index in start until end){
            if(arr[index]<arr[pivotIndex]){
                val temp = arr[index]
                arr[index] = arr[maximumElementIndex]
                arr[maximumElementIndex] = temp
                maximumElementIndex++
            }
        }

        val temp = arr[maximumElementIndex]
        arr[maximumElementIndex] = arr[pivotIndex]
        arr[pivotIndex] = temp
        return maximumElementIndex
    }
```

I have tested it on following inputs

- array with all equal elements
- sorted array
- sorted in reverse
- multiple random data set

so what I am missing here ?

Comment: Did your "random data set" test specifically include arrays that have multiple duplicates?

Comment: @JimMischel yes, I used this (1,5,5,5,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,1), and the output was correctly sorted

Comment: Test cases have to be carefully constructed with an understanding of how the partitioning will work. It's possible that the position of the duplicates within the partition will affect things. So unless your test cases cover all possibilities, there's no way to be sure. I've seen this happen before, causing a critical bug to escape to production. Testing with a few cases is no substitute for examining the algorithm and fully understanding its behavior. Unless you fully understand, then leave the `<=` comparison there. It doesn't cost anything.

Comment: @JimMischel I was looking for the explanation as to why the <= comparison is required and as far as testing is concerned I don't think exhaustive testing is possible, I would rather prove the correctness of algorithm using loop invariant.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to the differences than using `<=`. It's also initializing `i = p-1;`, and the final swap is `swap(A[i+1], A[r]);` . It's just a variation of Lomuto partition scheme. Your example code matches that in the Wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

Note that both schemes are worst case with already sorted data, reverse sorted data, and all equal elements, as the partition only reduces the size of the partition by 1 with each level of recursion. Using the middle value as pivot and swapping it to the end solves the issue with sorted or reverse sorted data, but Lomuto generally gets worse as the number of equal elements increases.

Hoare scheme, using middle element, usually gets better as the number of duplicates increases. There's needless swapping of elements equal to pivot value, but the partioning approaches the ideal case of evenly sized splitting as the number of duplicates increase, and cache helps with the unneeded swapping.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

Comment: I am aware of the efficiency of hoare's scheme. I just wanted to know if my implementation of lumoto's method is somehow incorrect because of the swap condition

Comment: @mightyWOZ - your code is the same as the wiki article. The book shows a variation of Lomuto.